# Is there a word for a last name that is also a word? If so, what is it?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, surnames

For example; Steve **Jobs**, Bill **Gates**, Warren **Buffet**, John **Doe**, Sweet **Brown** (all these last names are also *words*).

Comment: Yeah, I think "word" is what you're looking for.

Comment: I would say that the surname makes some literal sense but don't think there is an actual 'word' for it.

Comment: Would the word you're looking for also accommodate names like Zachary **Taylor** and David **Greene**, given that there is no word with the standard spelling _taylor_ or _greene_ in current English?

Comment: Here's a related question .. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235044/swr-surname-that-in-fact-describes-or-applies-to-the-human-in-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion you are facing is as a result of the fact that we have last names in English that are originally from other languages, where, in those languages, these last names are also meaningful words. To use your example, we have such last names as Braun, (German for "brown"), etc, which don't actually mean anything in English.

It is facing the contrast of such last names with English last names, which are meaningful words, that make them stand out.

Many last names come from professions (Taylor), and others from the compound of lineage (Johnson = "son of John"), so in reality, to some extent or another, *all* last names are "words" in the sense you are looking for, because *all* last names mean *something*... even if it's in another language, or their spelling has changed slightly over the years (as "Taylor" has).

So perhaps the answer to your question is a word hat means: "**meaningful word in English**" or "**word which means something in English**, and perhaps the best single-word that (unequivocally) means that is "**sensical**". There is also "meaningful" (as mentioned before), "coherent", "intelligible", "significant" and their synonyms, but these also have other, stronger connotations that might obscure what you mean.

Comment: An interesting question is: **In fact, does every surname in English, actually mean something (even if in another language)"**  Is that true?

Comment: @Joe Blow: Well, most surnames probably have **some** kind of origin. I think few people just invent a name out of nowhere to pass on to their offspring. But some names might have changed a lot from their original form, like those of immigrants that had their name changed to make it easier to pronounce.

Comment: If we could find a counter-example, that would solve that really fast (by proving the negative) proving the positive might be a little harder. WAlso, where would we draw the line? "Any last name in any language" is pretty broad, and would require checking, well, every last name in every language. As far as I've encountered all last names fall under those two categories: "sensical word" and "lineage identifier". Challenge is on, I guess.